# CMake cannot find OpenSSL library

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl, centos

I'm trying to build some code on Centos 8 that uses OpenSSL. When I run make it gives

> fatal error: openssl/core_names.h: No such file or directory

Source include  these files:

- `#include <openssl/core_names.h>`
- `#include <openssl/evp.h>`
- `#include <openssl/kdf.h>`

However I installed openssl from source and also installed with yum. When I check with which command I get output as follows:

**which openssl**

**/root/openssl-1.0.2r/builddir/bin/openssl**

I also installed with yum with this command:

`yum install openssl-devel`

Canyou help me to overcome this problem??

Comment: Did you already look if this specific header file is on your machine? Can you show how you instruct CMake to find OpenSSL?

Comment: If you are having problems with CMake, then you need to post your CMakeLists.txt file. That where the problem is likely to be.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I follow only instructions how to load openssl but when I locate the file name, it gives nothing

Comment: @BedirhanAteş If you haven't edited CMakeLists.txt to tell CMake where openssl is, then that explains the problem.

Comment: Search your system for the mentioned files. (or ask `yum` to tell you where it put them) `which openssl` searches for a **command** named openssl, which has nothing to do with the headers.

Comment: I have openssl installed openssl version -d
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
evp.h and kdf.h present in "/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl"